# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Nodejs/Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, socket.io

I have this set up where clients connect through a websocket to a server i have running on Nodejs.
The nodejs server does not serve any content!

The Apache is configured with this directives:

```
ServerName socket.mydomain.nl

RewriteEngine On
SSLEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:1900/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass / http://localhost:1900/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1900/

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.mydomain.nl/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.mydomain.nl/privkey.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.mydomain.nl/chain.pem
```

The clients connecting come from chat.mydomain.nl.

All goes well but in rare case i'm getting these CORS-messages after a period of time:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

and

```
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin   'https://chat.mydomain.nl' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

Strange thing is that messages that are broadcasted to all clients appear also on this particular client with the CORS-issues and itself can send messages that are broadcasted to all the others.
Messages however directed to this socket aren't getting through.

Someone having an idea what could be wrong? It's happening too often to ignore.

Comment: If you get a `503` status, it means that the server is unavailable (overloaded or any reason...), most probably your server is running out of resources.

Comment: Other clients connected don't get the 503 and CORS messages.